# Jquery onkeyup not working on boostrap modal. I'm using laravel blade template

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to auto compute the extract fee, estimated value and num vehicle after I input a value in to tonnage.

I used a Bootstrap modal for this but as soon I put a value in tonnage it doesn't work. I'm confused right now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('keyup', '#tonnage', function() {
    var tonnage = $("#tonnage").val();
    var num_vehicle;
    if (tonnage <= 20) {
      num_vehicle = 1;
      $("#num_vehicle").val(num_vehicle);
    } else {
      num_vehicle = tonnage / 20;
      $("#num_vehicle").val(num_vehicle);
    }

    var total_estimate_value = num_vehicle * 6000;
    $("#estimated_value").val(total_estimate_value);
    var total_extraction_fee = num_vehicle * 6000 * 0.1;
    $("#extraction_fee").val(total_extraction_fee);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6"> 
  <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">Volume/Tonnage</label> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tonnage" name="tonnage"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">Extraction Fee</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extraction_fee" name="extraction_fee" readonly="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">Estimated Value</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimated_value" name="estimated_value" readonly="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">No. of Vehicle</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_vehicle" name="num_vehicle" readonly="">
 </div>
```

Comment: my html form  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">Volume/Tonnage</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tonnage" name="tonnage">
                </div>

Comment: Can please you provide more detail that 'doesn't work'. What are you expecting to happen, and what does happen? Where is the rest of your HTML - the `#num_vehicle` and `#extraction_fee` fields are missing at least.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry my bad. I was expecting that after I put a value on "#tonnage" it will give me a automated computation for the "#num_vehicle", "#extraction_fee", and "#extraction_fee" but it doesn't compute after I put a value. I hope my explanation is clear

Comment: Thanks for editing the question - I posted an answer for you below.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thankyou it works but the problem is it only work on the edit side, as soon as I add a new record it doesn't auto compute.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is because you don't round the result of `tonnage / 20`, so you get a fraction of a vehicle, eg. `21` tons = `1.05` vehicles, instead of found up to the nearest integer, eg. `21` tons = `2` vehicles. This can be achieved using `Match.ceil()`.

Also, be careful of implicit type conversions from string to int/floats. It's better to be explicit with this, as in the following example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(document).on('keyup', '#tonnage', function() {  
    var tonnage = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var numberOfVehicles = Math.ceil(tonnage / 20);
    $('#num_vehicle').val(numberOfVehicles);
    
    var total_estimate_value = numberOfVehicles * 6000;
    $("#estimated_value").val(total_estimate_value);
    
    var total_extraction_fee = numberOfVehicles * 6000 * 0.1;
    $("#extraction_fee").val(total_extraction_fee);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">Volume/Tonnage</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tonnage" name="tonnage">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">Extraction Fee</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extraction_fee" name="extraction_fee" readonly="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">Estimated Value</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimated_value" name="estimated_value" readonly="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">No. of Vehicle</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_vehicle" name="num_vehicle" readonly="">
</div>
```